# How can I show/hide a section of the report without reloading the report?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have couple of sections in my report and by default they are all hidden,
I need to use an element inside the report that the moment I click it it shows a certain section and when I click it again it hides that section.
I prefer that it won't reload the report each time the user clicks on the element.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: so far I tried with parameters and "print when expression" but everytime I change the parameter it reloads the report also if it is possible I prefer to use an element inside the report itself.